# Mutates a cloned object, mutates the original object too [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, object, testing, jestjs, mutation

I'm writing some test for React Components with Jest in ES6. In one test, i need clone a json imported and mutate the cloned object, but when i mutate the object cloned, the original object mutates too!

```
import obj from './object.json';    // obj = { name: 'someName' }


describe('Testing a component', () => {

  it('Some testing', () => {
    const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj);  //Clone the object
    obj2.name = 'otherName';  // Muatate the object

    console.log(obj); // { name: 'otherName' }
  });

})
```

Why this happen? Why when i mutate the cloned object, the original imported object mutates too?

Comment: Do a deep clone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.assign` only does a shallow clone. That means the internal objects are still pointing to the original ones.

To do a deep clone you can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) or [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out for ages over this - couldn't fathom why Object.assign was still allowing the mutation of the original variable! Thank you for saving my sanity!

Comment: I get that you need to do a deep copy, but isn’t it expensive operation to do every time you want to map multi level javascript objects? A shallow copy is just useless once you have trees of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy an object properties with this function:

```
const copyObj = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]]).reduce((m, [k, v]) => {m[k] = v; return m}, {})
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/shnb6fkq/1/)